# Printing out extra 2 lines in my code

Tags: c, arrays, input, output

When I input the values in the document and print them out from the same loop, I print out the correct values. However as soon as I put the values after they were placed in the array in another loop about half way through I get the wrong values, the rest agree. Thanks for any help!

```
int main( ){

    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;

    float x, y, x1, y2;

    FILE *fp;

    /*open the file*/

    fp = fopen( "/Users/QuantumEh/Documents/datafiles/table.dat", "r" );

    /*creates array which allocates appropariate size*/


    float *x_axis = (float*) malloc( sizeof( fp ) );
    float *y_axis = (float*) malloc( sizeof( fp ) );

    if ( fp == NULL ){

        printf( "Could not open \n" );
        exit( 0 );
    }

    /*reads in the file*/

    while ( fscanf( fp, "%f %f\n", &x_axis[i], &y_axis[i] ) == 2 ){

        printf( "%.3f %.3f \n", x_axis[i], y_axis[i] );

        i++, n++;

    }



    /* calculates at one-third and then at two-thirds*/

    for ( i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++ ){


        x = x_of_interpolation_onethird( x_axis[i + 1], x_axis[i] ); //finds x of interpolation

        y = lagrange_interpolation( &x_axis[i], &y_axis[i], x ); //plugs in the orignal x and y and the x of interpolation

        x1 = x_of_interpolation_twothird( x_axis[i + 1], x_axis[i] ); //finds the other x of interpolation

        y2 = lagrange_interpolation( &x_axis[i], &y_axis[i], x1 ); //plugs in the orignal x and y and the x of interpolation


        /* prints out all the numbers*/

        //printf("%.3f %.3f \n", x_axis[i], y_axis[i]);
        //printf("%.3f \n", x1);
        //printf("%.3f %.3f\n", x, y);


    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: been awhile since I did C file IO, but I don't think sizeof(fp) will give you enough allocation.

Comment: `sizeof(fp)` is entirely unrelated to the "appropriate size" - when you allocate tiny arrays and write way off the end of them just about anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is that using the below code does *not* determine the amount of floating point values needed for the memory allocation.  The size of `fp` has nothing do do with the memory needed.

```
fp = fopen("/Users/QuantumEh/Documents/datafiles/table.dat", "r");
float *x_axis = (float*) malloc(sizeof(fp));
```

Instead use other methods.  One method, certain to work, but a bit inefficient, is to read the tile twice.

```
fp = fopen("/Users/QuantumEh/Documents/datafiles/table.dat", "r");
...
float x,y;
size_t n = 0;
while (fscanf(fp, "%f %f\n", &x, &y) == 2) n++;
float *x_axis = malloc(n * sizeof *x_axis);
float *y_axis = malloc(n * sizeof *y_axis);

rewind(fp);
size_t i = 0;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
  if (fscanf(fp, "%f %f\n", &x_axis[i], &y_axis[i])!=2) Handle_UnexpectedError();
} 
fclose(fp);

// Use x_axis, y_axis

// Be sure to free when done
free(x_axis);
free(y_axis);
```

Note: untested code.